Email to Case -Image not showing in Case record

Hello All,
I have OOB Email-to-Case process. I have a flow to copy HTML Body from
EmailMessage object to Case -> Description field(RichText). In
EmailMessage object I see the Image showing correctly. In Case Object
the Image is showing as broken link.
How I can fix this issue do I need to enable any setting or update my
flow.






Just confirming -- you have a custom Description__c field that is rich text? (the OOTB field is not rich text); 2) use [edit] and show the value of the image reference in the HTML body


@cropredy Yes Description__c is RictText. I am not using the OOB Text Description field.

what does the HTMLBody look like?  Use [edit] to modify the OP.  How does it compare to the Description__c field after you copy it via the Flow?
